# Missing template error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am a student and am working on an app, however i am getting this error

> Missing template jobs/index, application/index with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "

Im not sure how to decipher this, I started getting this when i created a show page, can someone offer some suggestions?

Show page:

```
<H1>Jobs Assigned to <%= @boat.name %></H1>


<% @boat.name.each do |job| %>


 <h3>Cargo Origin: <%= job.cargo_origin %></h3>
 <h3>Destination: <%= job.destination  %></h3>
 <h3>Containers Needed: <%= job.containers_needed %></h3>
 <h3>Cargo: <%= job.cargo %></h3>
 <h3>Job Cost: <%= job.job_cost %></h3>

 <% end %>
```

Jobs Controller:

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @jobs = Job.all
  end


  def show
    @job = Job.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to user_path 
  end

  def new
    @boat = Boat.find(params[:boat_id])
    @job = Job.new
  end

  def create
    @boat = Boat.find(params[:boat_id])
    @job = @boat.jobs.build(job_params) 
    @job.save
    redirect_to user_path (current_user)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
  end

  def destroy
  end


 private

  def job_params
    params.require(:job).permit(:cargo_origin,:destination,:containers_needed,:cargo,:job_cost).merge(user_id: current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Comment: At which line you get that error?

Comment: when it appear? after create or update?

Answer (score 1):

You should check existence of `app/views/jobs/index.html.erb` view. This view is being used when you visit `/jobs` path and being rendered by `JobsController#index` action.

Answer (score 0):

This error come due to non existence of views.
Create relevant views related o controllers and actions

For Controller Jobs and action index
Create `app/views/jobs/index.html.erb`

Like this create other views